# Encoding textfiles in utf-8 for xml import

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, text-files

I have created a java Applet that makes xml code, so an xml file can be imported by an Android App. The idea is to paste that xml into a text file and change the extension from .txt to .xml.

Now the problem is that a text file doesn't seem to be encoded while the app expects the xml file to be encoded in utf-8. If the file doesn't contain any special characters, all is fine. But when it contains characters like à or ° (°C) it fails.

Is there a way to make a text file encoded in utf-8? (Preferably not too difficult, because the users would have to do it)

Otherwise it is going to be signing applets or making making an application that creates the .xml files encoded. (and I would rather not get into signing applets)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're pasting from on-screen output into a text editor? What text-editor?

Comment: Many text editors allow you to set an UTF-8 encoding. Even Windows notepad can do it.

Comment: But Windows Notepad writes BOM even on UTF-8 output, which is not recommended.

Comment: "text file doesn't seem to be encoded" *all* text files are encoded, because computers use numbers not text; "encoded" means that text characters are converted into numbers and numbers are stored in the file. So, what encoding is your text file in already? Not US-ASCII, because it has some non ASCII characters? XML parsers do *not* require UTF-8; by placing an appropriate processing instruction in the XML you might be able to make the XML processor read whatever encoding you have.

Comment: @JonHanna I was using windows notepad

Comment: @THelper I now see notepad can do it aswell, i didn't know where to find it. (i overlooked the encoding drop-downbox in 'save as' and thought is simply wasn't possible)

Comment: I have already made a signed applet so I can write the file utf8-encoded to the user's pc, but I'll probably work out the non signed applet aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ supports UTF-8 both with and without BOM.